# PHP Regex grouping not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

So, I'll start off with posting some code:

```
$output = preg_replace([
  '/#(.*?)/i'
], [
  '<h1>$1</h1>'
], "#Input");
```

And that ended up outputting:

```
<h1></h1>
Input
```

In HTML OPT, the output I'd like to achieve is `<h1>Input</h1>` from inputting `#Input`, kind of like `Markdown`, but this is for a basic editing system.

I looked into a `Regex Debugger` ([here](https://www.regex101.com/)) and the debug/stack trace was that the first group was nothing, and the index group was the `#`.

To my knowledge, the only things that are taken and put into groups (I was told this) is `( ... )`'s, and from `left -> right` the groups are labelled from `$1 -> $x`.

Sorry for the overused REGEX questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra "?" in your Regex.

Try with:

```
$output = preg_replace([
  '/#(.*)/is'
], [
  '<h1>$1</h1>'
], "#Input");
```

Since you aren't matching any word-characters, case insensitivity doesn't make much sense, so you could write:

```
$output = preg_replace([
  '/#(.*)/s'
], [
  '<h1>$1</h1>'
], "#Input");
```

And of course, if this were the actual solution I'd try to be a bit narrower on my match definition (depending on your actual requirements). E.g.:

```
$output = preg_replace([
  '/#([^#\s]+)/s'
], [
  '<h1>$1</h1>'
], $string);
```

[Here](https://www.regex101.com/r/Xr4A0m/1) you have it working. And [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/Xr4A0m/2) the final version.

Comment: FYI: The `i` modifier is redundant here, and `.` with `s` modifier matches *any* characters which might be a problem in case the text the input is an already marked up string.

Comment: Not how I would construct this regex, just focusing on the immediate problem and I assume this is not the full code for the question, but your point is taken. I'll work on improving my answer for future visitors. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, apologies as it's just part of my code-base which required the `i` operator as much as the `s`, I'll remove the `s` from my for future visitors so there's no bad practise going around. @WiktorStribiżew and Answer OP

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the lazy dot matching pattern appears *at the end* of the pattern, and since it does not have to match any text, it does not. Your regex matches a `#` and captures empty string as Group 1.

If you mean to actually match something, use, say

```
'/#(\S+)/'
```

to match a `#` and capture 1 or more non-whitespace chars into Group 1.

Instead of `\S+`, you might want to use a more restricted pattern (like `\w+` for 1 or more word chars, `[^<]+` to match 1 or more chars other than `<`,  or `[^\s<]+`  to match 1+ chars other than whitespace and `<`).